Terms for pressure sensitive pads
I'm working on a project that needs pressure sensitive input, and I'm a bit lost on the lingo for parts. What would be a good search term to look for parts that describes a pressure sensitive pad that measures x/y location, force, velocity, etc.? No need for specific companies or products since I know that kind of question isn't allowed on here.

A Resistive touchscreen might meet the requirements given in the question.
With a suitable controller that allows measurement of position (X,Y) and pressure (Z). Software could potentially integrate changes to position to produce a velocity.
Products such as the Newhaven Display Resistive Touchscreen are available which could fitted as a "pad", although normally used as overlay on top of a LCD display.
ICs are available which contain integrated touch screen drivers and ADC, and and preprocessing of the touch screen measurements and have a I2C or SPI control interface to a host processor. E.g. the TSC2004 12-Bit, Nanopower, 4-Wire Touch Screen Controller from the range of TI Touchscreen controllers
